# Could not parse the remainder: '('-date_posted')' from 'post.answers_set.all.order_by('-date_posted')'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, jinja2

`{% for answer in post.answers_set.all.order_by('-date_posted') %}`

I am using this line to retrieve all Answers linked to this question in models.py. when I was working in django shell it works fine, but in django template it is showing weird error "Could not parse the remainder: '('-date_posted')' from 'post.answers_set.all.order_by('-date_posted')'". Is there any alternative, plz suggest. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filters in django template.

Create "templatetags" directory in app directory and then create "_*init*_.py" and "filters.py" files to it.

```
app_directory
    templatetags
          __init__.py
          filters.py
```

Leave _*init*_.py empty and add following code to filters.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def sort_by(queryset, order):
    return queryset.order_by(order)
```

Then you can use "sort_by" filter in html files after loading it:

```
<html lang="en">
{% load filters %}
<body>
{% for answer in post.answers_set.all|sort_by:'-date_posted' %}
    <p>{{ answer.pk }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```